# How does an OS know where the Touchpoints from a Touchpanel are on a Display Screen?

Tags: usb, report, hid, hdmi, edid

I am working on a software implementation of a touchpanel display - USB, and HDMI for the video.

I would have assumed that I would need some information in the USB descriptors that would tie it to the EDID of the display. But in the documentation I have read so far, I'm not seeing any mention of this.

If multiple monitors are plugged into the host, I presume the OS needs some way to work out which video display the touchpoints it receives from the HID reports correspond to. So that, if I had a hardware mouse plugged in, I can move the cursor to any display I want, but, touchpoints from the touch display only move the cursor within the boundaries of that display.

Is there something I need to do in order to achieve this? Or does any modern OS use some sort of heuristics to work out which monitor the USB device must belong to?

Thanks